# ANSI SQL - how to assign a row to a bucket based on a value change in the previous row

Tags: sql, window-functions, ansi-sql

If I have a table:

| id | url | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | about | page |
| 2 | contact | page |
| 3 | NULL | event |
| 4 | site2a | page |
| 5 | site2b | page |
| 6 | NULL | event |
| 7 | site3a | page |
| 8 | site3b | page |

How would I go about getting the following output? Essentially I'm looking to compare the 'type' in the row above (ordered by id) and, if the row above is an event and the current row is a page then create a new bucket. [I know we can use lag() but I can't make the counter for the buckets work]

OUTPUT:

| id | url | type | bucket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | about | page | 1 |
| 2 | contact | page | 1 |
| 3 | NULL | event | 1 |
| 4 | site2a | page | 2 |
| 5 | site2b | page | 2 |
| 6 | NULL | event | 2 |
| 7 | site3a | page | 3 |
| 8 | site3b | page | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

> I know we can use lag() but I can't make the counter for the buckets work

Well, first apply `LAG`, then apply `COUNT`:

```
select id, url, type, count(new_bucket) over (order by id) + 1 as bucket
from
(
  select
    id, url, type,
    case when type = 'page' and lag(type) over (order by id) = 'event'
      then 1 end as new_bucket
  from mytable
) bucket_changes_detected
order by id;
```

If it is guaranteed that events can only be followed by pages as in your sample data, then it even suffices to count events:

```
select
  id, url, type,
  count(case when type = 'event' then 1 end)
    over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 1 as bucket
from mytable
order by id;
```